# "JSON-LD Missing ',' or ']' in array declaration." but the code is the same

Tags: json

I have a blog where we add Schema to each post and what works perfectly and is validated by the SDTT then breaks on a new blog despite the only things changing is the content. I feel like I have been staring at the same 20 lines for hours. Can anyone see what might be different between these two.
Working Structured Data:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">// <![CDATA[
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "NewsArticle",
  "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "https://blog.realmanage.com/announcements/for-the-4th-time-in-five-years-realmanage-appears-on-the-inc.-5000"
  },
  "headline": "For the 4th time in Five Years, RealManage Appears on the Inc.5000",
  "image": ["https://blog.realmanage.com/hubfs/Inc%20Announcement.png"
   ],
  "datePublished": "2020-08-31T10:10:00+08:00",
  "dateModified": "2020-08-28T02:24:00+08:00",
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Amanda Causey"
  },
   "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "RealManage",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://www.realmanage.com/hs-fs/hubfs/Logo/RealManage_Logo_1.png?width=1324&name=RealManage_Logo_1.png"
    }
  },
  "description": "Inc. magazine today revealed that RealManage is No. 4646 on its annual Inc. 5000 list, the most prestigious ranking of the nation’s fastest-growing private companies. The list represents a unique look at the most successful companies within the American economy’s most dynamic segment—its independent small businesses. Intuit, Zappos, Under Armour, Microsoft, Patagonia, and many other well-known names gained their first national exposure as honorees on the Inc. 5000."
}
// ]]>
</script>
```

Non-working code:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">// <![CDATA[
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "NewsArticle",
  "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "https://blog.realmanage.com/creating-a-maintenance-chart-for-your-association-realmanage"
  },
  "headline": "Creating a Maintenance Chart for Your Association - RealManage",
  "image": [
    "https://f.hubspotusercontent20.net/hubfs/1849073/AdobeStock_396601443.jpeg”
   ],
  "datePublished": "2021-06-08T09:38:00+08:00",
  "dateModified": "2021-06-08T09:38:00+08:00",
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Katie Vaughan"
  },
   "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "RealManage",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://www.realmanage.com/hs-fs/hubfs/Logo/RealManage_Logo_1.png"
    }
  },
  "description": "When it comes down to who pays, the smallest dispute can blow into a neighborhood disaster.”
}
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: The coloring in Stack Overflow already gives you a hint..... The quote after that jpeg is not a standard `"` but a `”`, like those MS-Word uses to make a text *nicer*. There's another one after "disaster". You can paste the json [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) and validate it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't post to stack exchange often so I am not used to seeing the coding as it shows on the platform. I use Notepad+ (old school I know) when I update the contents but recently my new assistant began assisting me in adding this to our blogs and she must have used a word document to make the adjustments.

Again thank you so much for the solution, as I thought I was going mad trying to figure out what was missing.

Comment: I just added as an answer, so you can accept it and your question doesn't remain unanswered. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the quote after `396601443.jpeg”` is not a standard `"` but a `”`, like those Microsoft Word uses to make a text *nicer*. And there's another one closer to the end, after "disaster".

Bt the way, you can paste the JSON [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) and validate it.